# Chrome Custom Tabs and push notifications

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification, chrome-custom-tabs

When using an android app with chrome custom tabs, the push notifications can be registered there? And if so, they will apear in the chrome browser, outside the app? 
How does it behave?

Chrome Custom Tabs:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Web Push Notifications:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web

Comment: AFAIR we are not doing anything special in CustomTabs from notifications, so they should be able to register themselves and will land to regular chrome once delivered. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Right, I suposed that too, but don't have sure, please confirm it if you test it. Thanks

Comment: After some tests.. Yes it works, the notifications can be registered there.